# tkinter StringVar not print

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def button_func():
    print(string_var.get())


# window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Tkinter Variables')

# tkinter variable
string_var = tk.StringVar()

# widgets
label = ttk.Label(master=window, text='label', textvariable=string_var)
label.pack()

entry = ttk.Entry(master=window, textvariable=string_var)
entry.pack()

button = ttk.Button(master=window, text='button', command=button_func())
button.pack()

# run
window.mainloop()
```

I saw the fix of remove the parentheses, it work but really confused me.
New to python and tkinter, not sure is that the correct fix or some sort of mess up.

`button = ttk.Button(master=window, text='button', command=button_func)`

Comment: `command=button_func()` calls the function *once*, during the creation of the Button widget.  Nothing happens when you click the Button later, because None (the implicit return value of `button_func()` is what you passed as its command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here has indeed to do with "adding or removing parentheses"

All that is needed for your code to work is not to put parentheses on the call that creates the `Button`:

```
button = ttk.Button(master=window, text='button', command=button_func)
```

When you add a parentheses pair and do `button_func()`, that is just an ordinary function call - Python resolves it immediately: just call the function at this point, which is before the call to instantiate the Button itself - want is passed as the `command` argument is what is returned by the button_func (which, as it does not have a `return` statement is a `None` value).

When the parentheses are left out, which is the correct code, the function itself is passed as the command to be called back to tkinter.

Comment: This is simply not true: _"The thing is that a string var cannot be consumed in more than one widget and still be used with its get and set methods. "_. StringVars absolutely can be used by more than one widget at a time. In fact, that's one of their strengths. If you call `set` on a StringVar, every widget that uses that variable will instantly be updated.

Comment: I mean - I've just tried again with from scratch code, and then the OP snippet - and it just did work. 
I guess I had some problem with re-creating the `string_var` method when experimenting in the interactive mode the first time. I will strip down the answer and keep just the parentheses related parts